# ffmpeg jpg batch script with timestamp

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I currently have this batch script using ffmpeg to scale images and place in a new location with the same folder structure. How do i include the timestamp from the original jpg file in the filename of the new scaled jpg file?

This gives files named m-H-S_IMG_0305

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /a nfile=0
echo Copying directory structure from %1 to %2 ...
xcopy /T "%~1" "%~2"
REM walk directory structure and convert each file in quiet mode
set "sourcefolder=%~1"
set "targetfolder=%~2"
for /R "%sourcefolder%" %%a in (*.JPG) do (
    echo converting "%%~nxa" ...
    set "sourcefile=%%~fa"
    set "sourcepath=%%~dpa"
    set "targetfile=%%~na.JPG"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "targetfolder=%targetfolder%!sourcepath:%sourcefolder%=!"
    ffmpeg -v quiet -i "!sourcefile!" -vf scale=256x256 -q:v 1 -strftime 1 "!targetfolder!%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_!targetfile!"
    endlocal
    set /A nfile+=1
)
echo Done! Converted %nfile% file(s)
```

Working version for file modify date:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /a nfile=0
echo Copying directory structure from %1 to %2 ...
xcopy /T "%~1" "%~2"
REM walk directory structure and convert each file in quiet mode
set "sourcefolder=%~1"
set "targetfolder=%~2"
for /R "%sourcefolder%" %%a in (*.JPG) do (
    echo converting "%%~nxa" ...
    echo which has a timestamp of "%%~ta" ...
    set "sourcefile=%%~fa"
    set "sourcepath=%%~dpa"
    set "targetfile=%%~na.JPG"
    set "timestamp=%%~ta"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "timestamp=!timestamp: =_!"
    set "timestamp=!timestamp::=-!"
    set "timestamp=!timestamp:/=-!"
    set "targetfolder=%targetfolder%!sourcepath:%sourcefolder%=!"
    ffmpeg -v quiet -i "!sourcefile!" -vf scale=256x256 -q:v 1 "!targetfolder!!timestamp!_!targetfile!"
    endlocal
    set /A nfile+=1
)
echo Done! Converted %nfile% file(s)
```

File Creation date option attempt using exiftool (This works but it stops frequently so there is an error somewhere):

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /a nfile=0
echo Copying directory structure from %1 to %2 ...
xcopy /T "%~1" "%~2"
REM walk directory structure and convert each file in quiet mode
set "sourcefolder=%~1"
set "targetfolder=%~2"
for /R "%sourcefolder%" %%a in (*.JPG) do (
    echo converting "%%~nxa" ...
    echo which has a timestamp of "%%~ta" ...
    set "sourcefile=%%~fa"
    set "sourcepath=%%~dpa"
    set "targetfile=%%~na.JPG"
    set "timestamp=('exiftool -d %%Y%%m%%d_%%H%%M%%S -CreateDate %%~a')"
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=x" %%a in ('exiftool -T -d %%Y%%m%%d_%%H%%M%%S -CreateDate "%%a"') do (
        set "timestamp=%%a"
    )
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "targetfolder=%targetfolder%!sourcepath:%sourcefolder%=!"
    ffmpeg -v quiet -i "!sourcefile!" -vf scale=256x256 -q:v 1 "!targetfolder!!timestamp!_!targetfile!"
    endlocal
    set /A nfile+=1
)
echo Done! Converted %nfile% file(s)
```

Comment: I am going to assume that `%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S` are ffmpeg internal variables.  If so , then you need to double the percent symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /R "%sourcefolder%" %%a in (*.JPG) do (
    echo converting "%%~nxa" ...
    echo which has a timestamp of "%%~ta" ...
    set "sourcefile=%%~fa"
```

Then analyse "%%~ta" for the required elements and re-assemble as appropriate. Without knowing your date/time format, precise directions becomes a tome.

---

Ok, so here's a skeleton ... and it isn't even Halloween!

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d *') DO (
 SET "newfile=Y"
 FOR /f "skip=4delims=" %%q IN ('dir /a-d /-c /tc "%%b"') DO IF DEFINED newfile (
 SET "newfile="
 ECHO %%~tb %%q
 )
)
```

This should yield a line of the format

```
createdate createtime updatedate updatetime size name
```

for each file. Note the `/-c` option removes the thousands-separator in the `size` field - not useful here, but might be useful in future.

So- you've shown that you can extract the relevant elements and re-assemble them. Next step is to correctly place the `setlocal` family.

```
for /R "%sourcefolder%" %%a in (*.JPG) do (
    set "timestamp=%%~ta"
    set "timestamp=!timestamp: =_!"
    ... more timestamp manipulation etc ...
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "targetfolder=%targetfolder%!sourcepath:%sourcefolder%=!"
    ffmpeg -v quiet -i "!sourcefile!" -vf scale=256x256 -q:v 1 "!targetfolder!!timestamp!!targetfile!"
    endlocal
    set /A nfile+=1
)
```

should be

```
for /R "%sourcefolder%" %%a in (*.JPG) do (
    set "timestamp=%%~ta"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "timestamp=!timestamp: =_!"
    ... more timestamp manipulation etc ...
    set "targetfolder=%targetfolder%!sourcepath:%sourcefolder%=!"
    ffmpeg -v quiet -i "!sourcefile!" -vf scale=256x256 -q:v 1 "!targetfolder!!timestamp!!targetfile!"
    endlocal
    set /A nfile+=1
)
```

since the `!var!` reference is only active in `delayedexpansion` mode.

That should cure the `!timestamp!` problem

Preferably, do the entire task in `delayedexpansion` mode by adding `enabledelayedexpansion` on the very first `setlocal` (your very first line) and remove the remaining `setlocal` and `endlocal` commands altogether.

Of course, there's the minor problem of converting to 24-hour clock times (if desired) and possibly generating `timestamp` in (YY)YYMMDDHHSS format so the resultant filenames are in alphabetical order of date.

See... told you it was a tome...

---

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "fields=dd mm yyyy hh mn ampm"
FOR /r %%e IN (*) DO (
 FOR %%b IN (c a w) DO (
  FOR %%c IN (%fields%) DO SET "#%%b%%c="
  FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%u IN ('dir /a-d /t%%b /-c "%%e"^|findstr /v /b /c:" "^|findstr /i /e /c:" %%~nxe"') DO (
   SET "filedata=%%u %%v %%w"
   FOR %%y IN (/ - . : ",") DO CALL SET "filedata=%%filedata:%%~y= %%"
   FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%q IN ('set filedata') DO IF /i "%%q"=="filedata" FOR %%y IN (%%r) DO (
    SET "placed="
    FOR %%c IN (%fields%) DO IF NOT DEFINED placed IF NOT DEFINED #%%b%%c SET "#%%b%%c=%%y"&SET "placed=Y"
   )
  )
 )

 ECHO FOR %%e
 SET #
 ECHO ==========
)
```

I tinkered a bit.

The problem with dealing with file date/time data is that there are many formats, all multiplied by there being three distinct timestamps per file. Hence this snippet.

The outer shell uses `%%e` to define the filename under examination. No big problem there.

Next step is to use `%%b` to control the timestamp (**C**reated, **A**ccessed and **W**ritten) being processed.

Then we examine the `dir` listing. The first `findstr` disposes of the lines that start with a space, and the second selects only the line that ends with <kbd>space</kbd>filename, which should reliably detect only the line containing the date/time data for the file.

This data, afaiaa, will contain three groups; date, time and amp/pm indicator. These are applied to `%%u`, `%%v` and `%%w`. String these together and assign to `filedata`, then replace each of the filed-separators with spaces. The result in `filedata` will be a space-separated list of the values retrieved from the `dir` listings.

I'm trying to avoid the use of `delayedexpansion`, so using `=` as a separator, just tokenise the `set` output (in the format `filedata=fieldvaluelist`) to `%%q` and `%%r` respectively. The value in `%%q` is matched to `filedata` (in case a variable like `filedataold` exists) and then process `%%r`.

This is where `fields` comes in. It contains the fieldnames in the sequence that are used on *your* machine. I use `dd/mm/yy hh:mn`. A US user would typically use  `dd-mm-yy hh:mn am/pm`.

`%%r` will contain six values. Each is assigned in turn via `%%y` to each of the undefined variables in the list of `fields`. `placed` is a flag that ensures that the candidate in `%%y` is only assigned once.

Hence, on my machine, the variables `#cdd #cmm #cyyyy #chh #cmn #cmpm` to the file's **C**reate-dd, etc.

On a typical US machine, simply change the `fields` list to `mm dd yyyy hh mn ampm` and the variables will be appropriately assigned.

`ampm` should not be omitted from the `fields` list. The value assigned to `?ampm` will be junk (actually the filesize) if am/pm is not used.

The object is simply to grab all of the timestamp data into separate fields. Actually *using* that data is a whole nother thing. The programmer should be aware of whether the ampm indicator values are valid and whether fields may contain leading zeroes in conducting further manipulation.

(here endeth tome volume 2)

Comment: Okay so now that I have the last Modify date, how does this get incorporated into the filename.     set "targetfile=%%~ta_%%~na.JPG" for example?

Comment: adding set "timestamp=%%~ta"  and     ffmpeg -v quiet -i "!sourcefile!" -vf scale=256x256 -q:v 1 "!targetfolder!!timestamp!!targetfile!" didn't work either

Comment: Without knowing your date/time format, precise directions becomes a tome.

Comment: Does this help? This is an example of what adding your line in outputs 
which has a timestamp of "20/11/2019 10:44 PM" ...   I guess i need to get rid of the / and : to add it to the filename right? Also wondering if it is possible to get the Date File Created rather than Date File Modified

Comment: I've updated the question with what must be getting close to incorporating the File modify date into the filename

Comment: Okay, so the file modify date version is now working thanks to that last little edit you made. I know getting files named 20-11-2019_17-02_IMG_0063.JPG Thank you! @Magoo. Unfortunately, I am completely lost when it comes to incorporating my script into the premature Halloween skeleton you have provided. I normally use R, but it is horrifically slow at this type of manipulation.

Comment: Thanks @Magoo. Hmm quite a bit involved here. I'll keep tinkering and see how I go.